# Can I use same variable name in macro

Tags: c, variables, macros

I wrote a code like below.

Test Macro 1 uses a variable which has same name (`nCount`) from what it is called.
And Test Macro 2 uses a different named variable.

I thought the variable of Macro 1 is regarded as different one, because it is packed by square brackets.

But the value of variable in function is change to macro's value.
(You can see the result in tracelog result.)

On the other hand, the Macro 2 which uses different named variable is ok.

Could somebody explain why this thing is happening?

```
=====================Trace Log======================================
[MACRO_1] size = 5 / nCount = 5, (0x2b9d84) 
[MACRO_2] size = 10 / nCount = 5, (0x2b9da4)
```

(I thought size value in Macro 1 was also 10, but it was 5)

Source code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TEST_MACRO_1(size)      \
{                               \
    if(0 < size)                \
    {                           \
        int nCount = 5;         \
        printf("[MACRO_1] size = %d / nCount = %d, (0x%x)\n", (int)size, nCount, &nCount);  \
    }                           \
}

#define TEST_MACRO_2(size)      \
{                               \
    if(0 < size)                \
    {                           \
        int nCount2 = 5;        \
        printf("[MACRO_2] size = %d / nCount = %d, (0x%x)\n", (int)size, nCount2, &nCount2);  \      
    }                           \
}

int main()
{
    int nCount = 10;

    TEST_MACRO_1(nCount);  // Macro 1
    TEST_MACRO_2(nCount);  // Macro 2
}
```

Comment: Double tagging for two different languages, highly unreadable code, no clear explanaition, use of names tarting with two underscores (reserved for the implementation) … What do you want to accomplish? Don't get too fancy with macros, you will eventaully end up in macro hell. You wrote that code, so you tell what it is supposed to do and what does not work.

Comment: C++ has ideal things for such task: inline functions (modern C too)

Comment: Thank you @Olaf. And Sorry for my code. I just made a testing code to explain. I will fix the code to make more clear. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @JacekCz Thanks for your advice. I will use inline instead of macro. But i wanna know why this thing is happened. My knowledge is getting messed. :-)

Comment: @JacekCz: `inline` functions are just a hint; the compiler is free to ignore it. Modern compilers will inline at theior own disretion and heuristics, they mostly ignore `inline`. With LTO it has become mostly obsolete (at the costs of increased build-times, though, but that is normally done for release only anyway.

Comment: @Olaf: Well the purpose of this code to check if I can use same named variable at outside of macro. I thought the trace log of Macro Test 1 and Test 2 were same, but it wasn't.

Comment: @chanhongPark: Actually that's what you are asking. So it cannot be the purpose of that code! The purnpose of that code seems to be the to obfuscate your code.

Comment: @Olaf Sorry for what I make you feel uncomfortable. I will rewrite the code simple.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because it contains everything needed to answer it. It's just that nobody was able to figure it out until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what happens:

**Macro 1:**

When the compiler expands

```
TEST_MACRO_1(nCount);  // Macro 1
```

it replaces every instance of `size` in the macro's replacement list with `nCount`. This is the result (after adding linebreaks and indenting it for readability):

```
int nCount = 10;

/* expansion of Macro 1 */
{
    if(0 < nCount)
    {
        int nCount = 5;
        printf("[MACRO_1] size = %d / nCount = %d, (0x%x)\n", (int)nCount, nCount, &nCount);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the inner `nCount` shadows the outer and the code prints 5 instead of 10.

**Macro 2:**

Similarly, when the compiler expands

```
TEST_MACRO_2(nCount);  // Macro 2
```

`size` is again replaced with `nCount` and the result becomes:

```
int nCount = 10;

/* expansion of Macro 2 */
{
    if(0 < nCount)
    {
        int nCount2 = 5;
        printf("[MACRO_2] size = %d / nCount = %d, (0x%x)\n", (int)nCount, nCount2, &nCount2);
    }
}
```

Here, the inner variable is `nCount2`, so nothing is being shadowed and the code prints the outer `nCount` which is 10.

Comment: Thank you Nisse for your advice. I edited the code on your advice and I posted it again. Unfortunately, the result is still same. Is there anything what I missunderstand?

Comment: Your current code passes too many values to `printf()`. Your previous version passed pointers using the wrong format specifier (`"%p", (void)&nCount` is one possible solution).

Comment: @chanhongPark: I figured it out and rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I clearly understand. Thank you!